# gwt application logging, profiling, benchmarking

Tags: debugging, logging, gwt, profiling, benchmarking

Is there a good methodology for logging/benchmarking/profiling a gwt application to identify bottlenecks?

Something like a timing/logging framework or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- For logging, there's [GWT.log](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.6/com/google/gwt/core/client/GWT.html) and [gwt-log](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-log/)
- Benchmarking - the official docs have a nice section about this: http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/1.6/DevGuideTesting.html#DevGuideJUnitBenchmarking, you can also have a look at this [blog post](http://googlewebtoolkit.blogspot.com/2008/11/profiling-gwt-application-performance.html)

I especially recommend the last link - Firebug's profiling can be very helpful when combined with `-style PRETTY`.

And, in general, any profiling solution that works for Javascript, should work for GWT.

Answer (score 0):

IE8 has an excellent profiler too, extremely useful.  It's call-tree mode is superb.

Of course, IE8 needs profiling tools far more than other browsers; it's a complete dog, performance-wise.