# How to profile a gwt client application with jprofiler?

Tags: java, gwt, jprofiler

I have a memory leak problem in my GWT application and I'm trying to profile it using JProfiler.

I can't manage to get pertinent results as I don't see my java classes on the profile memory view, i just see the GWT lib classes.

I've added the parameter to profile a remote application using JProfiler (-agentpath:C:\PROGRA~1\JPROFI~1\bin\WINDOW~1\jprofilerti.dll=port=8849). I launch the project in superDevMode through the Eclipse IDE. JProfiler shows me the GWT classes in memory but it doesn't show my own java classes.

In this video youtube.com/watch?v=zUJUSxXOOa4 we can see that JProfiler can show the java classes directly, that's what i search to do

Is there any option to activate in JProfiler for that ? Any help on that matter would be welcome. Thank you

Comment: check this out-> http://stackoverflow.com/a/1628863/3472757

Comment: possible duplicate of [gwt application logging, profiling, benchmarking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628031/gwt-application-logging-profiling-benchmarking)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Super Dev mode** does not work with a Java profiler. The old **Dev mode** executed the client-side code in the JVM via a special plugin. These days, the Dev mode browser plugin does not work with modern browsers. The last browsers that supported the plugins were  Chrome  21.0.1180.89 and Firefox 26.

As of now, Firefox 24 ESR is still supported:

https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/organizations/all/

and the Dev mode plugin works in that version. For more information on dev mode see

http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging.html

Comment: That said, using JProfiler with GWT code in classic Dev Mode is not profiling how fast your code is or how much memory it uses in the browser, it is measuring how much memory your code uses in Dev Mode, which is not the same. if you want to actually measure browser performance, use a browser performance tool.

Comment: Sure, but if something is really slow, the general characteristics are mostly the same. I've found more than one GWT performance bottleneck with JProfiler and I'm quite sad that dev mode is going away.

Comment: Sometimes you are right, but other times you will be wildly wrong - if DOM manipulation is slow in Dev mode, it will often be fast in prod, if math is fast in dev mode, it will often be slow in prod. Any JSNI has massive performance overhead in dev, and is free in prod, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much for these links.
Ok, so do you know a profiling tool which can profile the js code produced by gwt and show the java class that make a memory leak (showing the number of instances used by the application) ?

Comment: @ColinAlworth DOM manipulation is still done in the browser, it's just the program logic that is executed in the code server. That logic executes somewhat differently, but since the bottlenecks mostly come from slow DOM manipulations, it really doesn't matter. In my experience, the measured performance characteristics were never wildly wrong in the case of a bottleneck.

Comment: @NicolasTeillet As Colin Alworth said, you can use a browser tool, like Firebug. The point of Super Dev mode is that you are able to see the Java classes and method names and not meaningless generated symbols.

Comment: @IngoKegel not just super dev mode, but any PRETTY or DETAILED build. Super Dev Mode has the added disadvantage (in this case) of having disabled most optimizations. This can mean added junk to confuse matters, I'd aim for as little code running as possible, but its not a requirement - the tools do work with sdm.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. GWT compile your classes to JS, due to this JProfiler won't work (I think, but maybe I'm wrong). Maybe you can give a try to MemoryAnalyzer with a Heap dump.

Comment: In this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zUJUSxXOOa4 we can see that JProfiler can show the java classes directly, that's what i search to do

Comment: Ok, sorry. I didn't know that.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome comes with some awesome built-in CPU and heap profiling tools. Firefox now has its own built-in CPU profiler, and Firebug has a different one. IE (at least 10, and I think 9) has a built in CPU profiler, though it has been a long time since I dug too far into there.

Memory is historically a difficult thing to track in browsers, not least because old IE versions just won't die, and leak just from looking at them funny. If you are facing one of *those* memory leaks, a different plan of attack is required.

But if you suspect you are dealing with a leak in your own application code, Chrome's dev tools can help! Compile in `PRETTY` (or `DETAILED` if you have an extremely wide screen), and bring up your app in Chrome with the developer tools open.

In the Profiles tab, there are three kinds of profile to capture, two about memory. I typically prefer the Take Heap Snapshot, and take a 'before' and 'after' look at whatever action I believe to be leaking memory, but the Record Heap Allocations view will give you another way to consider the memory usage of your application.

Start by picking a supposedly 'stable' state of your memory usage - turn the app on, use it for a bit, make sure all the various singletons etc are instantiated, and probably do whatever action you suspect as causing a problem, once. Once you are at a point which you can back to (memory-wise, at least if the leak was fixed), take a snapshot, do the behavior that leaks, return to the 'stable' state, and take another snapshot. Only take one step when checking for leaks, more on this in a bit.

With the two snapshots, you can compare objects allocated and freed - we're mostly interested in cases where more objects were created than deleted, ideally where zero were deleted. If you find N objects are deleted but N+1 are created, then make sure N is veeeery small before digging in - it is often possible to fix a leak only by going after individual objects, tracing them back to their actual leaked source, fixing it, and measuring again.

Once you have an object that was created in one step, but not deleted at the end of that step (but it should have been) use the 'Retainers' view to see why they are still kept. This will more or less show you the field in the object that holds them and the type of that holding object, all the way up to `window` or some other global object.

Ignore anything in ()s like `(compiled code)`, `(array)`, `(system)`, `(string)`, etc. I'd *generally* ignore dom element allocation (assuming you suspect you have a leak in app code, not JSNI). Look for few, high level objects leaked, rather than many, low level, it will make it more likely that you are closer to the source of the leak.

The names of compiled constructors and fields in `PRETTY` *generally* map very closely to the original Java source. All constructors get `_X` appended to them, where `X` is 0, 1, etc - this is to distinguish from the type itself. This makes for an easy way to recognize Java types in the Constructor column, as they all have `_`s near the end of their name.